# GridView in android ClassCastException

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, classcastexception

I am trying to modify google sample http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html.
This sample fetches image from internet using asynctask and display in gridview. What I am trying to do is to display text below the images. I am getting exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`

Below is the code:

1. getView Method

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
       //BEGIN_INCLUDE(load_gridview_item)
       // First check if this is the top row
       if (position < mNumColumns) {
           if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = new View(mContext);
           }
           // Set empty view with height of ActionBar
           convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
           return convertView;
       }

       // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
       View vi = convertView;
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       if (convertView == null)  // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize

           vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);
           TextView textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
           textView.setText("Sample text");
           //imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
           imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
           imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);


           // Check the height matches our calculated column width
       if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
           imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
       }

           // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
           // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
           mImageFetcher.loadImage(Images.imageThumbUrls()[position - mNumColumns], imageView);
           return vi;
           //END_INCLUDE(load_gridview_item)

   }
   ```
2. Exception

   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:651)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:558)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
           at android.widget.GridView.setupChild(GridView.java:1425)
           at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1342)
           at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:344)
           at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:286)
           at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:419)
           at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1231)
           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1875)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1642)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1418)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
3. ImageGridFragment.xml

> ```
> <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/gridView"
>     style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
>     android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
>     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
>     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
>     android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
>
> </GridView>
> ```

4. row_gridview.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:padding="5dp"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/grid_image"
>         android:layout_width="50dp"
>         android:layout_height="50dp"
>         android:background="#FF0000"/>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/grid_text"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>         android:textSize="9sp"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: You did not post your xml code, but I'm guessing you added a LinearLayout inside each grid box?  Also, what is the type of mImageViewLayoutParams and where is it set?

Comment: @GaryBak I have updated the XMLs and mImageViewLayoutParams is of type GridView.LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
```

instead of

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
```

Comment: I tried it already but got exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams); Check also this lines. Try to comment it step by step and change LayoutParams for every method call to needed one.